# Animation I created with spring is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, react-spring

The codes I wrote for spring are below. My code is not working even though there are no errors.

```js
export default function heroImage() {
  return (
    <div className="heroImage">
    <img className="sliderBackground" src={Background} />
    <Spring
    from={{ opacity:0, marginTop:-500 }}
    to={{ opacity:1, marginTop:0 }}
    >
    {
      props => (
      <div style={props}>
      <div style={sliderContentStyle}>
      <h2 style={sliderH2Style} lang="tr">En iyi Yerel Lezzetler Menzil'de</h2>
      <p style={sliderPStyle}>Taze kuruyemişler, Sağlıklı besinler ve sofralarınıza lezzet katacak baharatlar için Menzil'e gelin</p>
      <img className="sliderFoto" src={SliderFoto} />
      </div>
      </div>
    )}
    </Spring>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you built the component `Spring` yourself?

Comment: @hellogoodnight yes, but I imported the component.

Comment: You need to show the code of that component since it's the one that is not working.